# ECSlidingViewController disabling swipe to delete in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ecslidingviewcontroller

I'm using this source code for adding a sliding menu similar to the Facebook App:

Git Hub Project ECSlidingViewController: https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController

Here is the code for my Custom UINavigation Controller:

```
@implementation NavViewController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (![self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController isKindOfClass:[ZAPMenuViewController class]])
    {
        self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController  = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Menu"];
    }

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.slidingViewController.panGesture];
}
```

However, I have a UITableView and I need to be able to swipe to delete. Is there a way to disable the panGesture when swiping the the left, but leave the panGesture for swiping to the right and revealing the menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also check out some answers on ECSlidingViewController's [wiki](https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#wiki-the-pan-gesture-conflicts-with-my-tables-swipe-to-delete-gesture-or-some-other-gesture-what-do-i-do) which include allowing simultaneous gestures to be recognized.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer
 *)otherGestureRecognizer {
     if ([otherGestureRecognizer.view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
         return YES;
     } else {
         return NO;
     } }
```

Comment: Where should this delegate implemented ? this question is because ECSlidingViewController added with pod and edit is not available

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can use UIView placed in the "background" of your controller and connect panGesture to it. So instead of

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.slidingViewController.panGesture];
```

I used UIView outlet

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *slideOutArea;
```

and then in proper method like viewWillAppear

```
[self.slideOutArea addGestureRecognizer:self.slidingViewController.panGesture];
```